# Join tables on string value

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables A and B. Each of them has a column "name" of type string. I want to get all records from joining operation where A.name is a sub string of B.name.

```
select * from A inner join B on A.name like concat('%',B.name,'%');
```

The result is a empty table. Something goes wrong with that query, because I got results if I test it via

```
select * from A cross join B where A.name like 'test' and B.name like '%test%';
```

There for I got some records for the static value "test".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first query is matching B as substring of A. You need:

```
select * from A inner join B on B.name like concat('%',A.name,'%');
```

or

```
select * from A inner join B on position(A.name in B.name) > 0;
```

Comment: `on position(A.name in B.name)` is invalid. You need a boolean expression for the join condition. e.g. `on position(A.name in B.name) > 0`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for the correction. didn't know about this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `A.name` being a substring of `B.name`, then then expression is `B.name LIKE '%A.name%'`.  Try this:

```
select *
from A inner join B
on B.name like '%A.name%'
```